# Where in the hello world assembly program is the segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, nasm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xfce

I have written my first assembly program

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Writes "Hello, World" to the console using only system calls. Runs on 64-bit Linux only.
; To assemble and run:
;
;   nasm -felf64 hello.asm && ld hello.o && .a.out
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            global      _start

            section     .text
_start      mov         rax, 1                      ; system call for write
            mov         rdi, 1                      ; file handle 1 is stdout
            mov         rsi, message                ; address of string to output
            mov         rdx, 13                     ; number of bytes
            syscall                                 ; invoke operating system to do the write
            mov         rax, 60                     ; system all for exit
            xor         rdi, rdi                    ; exit code 0

            section     .data

message:    db          "Hello, world", 10          ; note the newline at the end
```

using [gedit](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/) text editor in Ubuntu studio 20.04 64bits system. I ran the program using Xfce terminal using command **nasm -felf64 hello.asm && ld hello.o && ./a.out** and received the output on two lines:

> Hello, world

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I got the source code from [nasm tuitorial](https://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/nasmtutorial/) webpage. So where in this program is the segmentation fault

Comment: The CPU doesn't know when to stop executing code, You've cleared `rdi`, but never `_exit`.

Comment: So how should I fix that?

Comment: You set up the registers for the `_exit` system call but you never actually executed the `syscall` instruction.  Add `syscall` after `xor rdi, rdi` and it works.  That line is present in the tutorial so I guess you missed copying it.

Comment: Ah! Muchas gracias for that, I didn't notice it in the source code. Thanks again.